# How do I access Azure Cognitive Services Custom Vision non-US endpoints?

Tags: azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

A simple question:

What are some other endpoints for the Custom Vision service, apart from southcentralus?

I have had no luck in asking Azure support directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Vision is now "Generally Available" from many different Azure Regions. See here for the growing list:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?products=cognitive-services [sic]

Answer (score 3):

As of today, only `southcentralus` is available.

The service being in preview, it will certainly be available in other regions once released.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Any idea on timescales for a release?

Comment: No exact date, subscribe at the [roadmap](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/roadmap/cognitive-services-custom-vision-service/) to me notified.

Comment: According to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/roadmap/microsoft-cognitive-services-custom-vision-service-api/, this is now "generally available", but https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services implies the only endpoint is still southcentralus. Are other (european) endpoints now available? Thanks!